# Payment Gateway for USDT payment

Tags: payments

I have come across a few crypto-payment providers offering USDT payment solutions. Basically, they generate a new wallet address for each transaction and let a user make a USDT deposit within a certain time frame such as 5 mins. It looks like they are create a sub-wallet address as per transaction which is basically tied to their one master account.

I have researched about this across this forum and seems like a smart contract needs to be leveraged.

Can anyone explain how this system is structured ?